# Installing Mosquitto on Raspeberry Pi disabling internet

Tags: raspberry-pi

Im trying to use Node-red to save the readings from DHT sensors and display it on a dashboard using mosquitto as a broker, I have installed the latest version of Node-red and mosquitto yet, currently, my raspeberry pi cannot connect to the internet without an ethernet cable, displaying DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET whenever I try to open a web page. even with an ethernet cable I cannot connect to the node-red server with another computer connected to the same internet, I have changed the static ip already on dhcpcd.conf.

These are the logs displayed on syslog https://pastebin.com/wwTSeS0X

Comment: Unfortunately this question is more about linux system administration than programming so is off topic for Stack Overflow. It may be on topic for [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) but you are going to need to supply a LOT more detail about how you are installing things.

Comment: p.s. as a guess this will be down to `/etc/hosts` or systemd-resolv

Comment: Probably unrelated, but do the sensors work? There are `w1_master_driver` registration errors - see https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=196691. Can you please provide relevant configurations in the question - anything related to networking, Mosquitto and Node-Red? When the RasPi is unable to connect to the internet, can it ping other hosts in the same network?

Comment: Im planning to connect the sensors with another laptop and send the information to the raspeberry. And no i cant ping other hosts in the same network.